# i get in my terminal raise DecryptionError("Decryption failed") rsa.pkcs1.DecryptionError: Decryption failed

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

```
import rsa

(pubkey, privkey) = rsa.newkeys(512)
with open('keys/pubkey.pem', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pubkey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))
with open('keys/privkey.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(privkey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))

d = open('encryptedmsg.txt', 'r')
encrypted = d.read()

converted = (bytes(encrypted, encoding='utf8'))

message = rsa.decrypt(converted, privkey)
print(message.decode('utf8'))
```

basicly i m trying to make this to decrypt a message  in encrptedmsg.txt but then it is #a str but rsa library only uses bytes which means i have to convert from st to bytes but #when i do this it gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Documents\coding\encryption\test2.py", line 14, in <module>
    message = rsa.decrypt(converted, privkey)
  File "C:\UsersAppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rsa\pkcs1.py", line 264, in decrypt
    raise DecryptionError("Decryption failed")
rsa.pkcs1.DecryptionError: Decryption failed
PS C:\Users\\Documents\coding\encryption>
```

thank you, in advanced

Comment: Show the code for encryption.

Comment: If it is a text file I would suspect something that is hex or base 64 encoded, in that case I would not expect UTF-8 encoding to work.